# How to close goroutines after channel has been shut

Tags: go, channel

I'm trying to write a program which concurrently mines a block of bitcoin. I have set it up so that each goroutine has an initial starting nonce each of which is a fraction of 4 ie. 2**64 - 1 (max number of uint64 type) / 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.

Only one of these miners will come across the correct nonce and when that happens I would like it to pass it to the miner manager through a channel and when this happens I would like the other 3 miners to stop what they're doing.

The only problem is I have no idea how to destroy a running goroutine, or if there is even a way to do what I'm asking.

```
func miner(blockNumber int, transactions string, previousHash string, zeroPrefix string, startNonce uint64, nonceChan chan uint64, hashChan chan string) {
    var text string
    var newHash string

    for {
        text = strconv.Itoa(blockNumber) + transactions + previousHash + strconv.FormatUint(startNonce, 10)
        newHash = encrypt(text)

        if startswith(newHash, zeroPrefix) {
            nonceChan <- startNonce
            hashChan  <- newHash

            close(nonceChan)
            close(hashChan)
            break
        } else {
            startNonce++
        }
    }
}

func mine(blockNumber int, transactions string, previousHash string, zeroPrefix int) Block {
    var prefixString string
    var newHash string
    var nonce uint64
    var startNonce uint64

    nonceChan := make(chan uint64)
    hashChan := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < zeroPrefix; i++ {
        prefixString += "0"
    }

    start := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++{
        // This line is for deciding at what nonce value a miner should start at.
        startNonce = uint64((float64(i) / 4) * math.Pow(2, 64))

        go func() {
            fmt.Println("Started miner with start nonce of", startNonce)
            miner(blockNumber, transactions, previousHash, prefixString, startNonce, nonceChan, hashChan)
        }()
    }

    nonce = <- nonceChan
    newHash = <- hashChan

    // Here is where I would like to destroy the other three miners

    block := Block{
        blockNumber,
        transactions,
        previousHash,
        newHash,
        nonce,
        zeroPrefix,
        time.Since(start),
    }

    return block
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `context` which is one of the typical object to handle go routine's termination.

`context :` Package context defines the Context type, which carries deadlines, cancellation signals, and other request-scoped values across API boundaries and between processes.

`ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())` with this you can create a `context` with `cancel` func.

Just pass `ctx and cancel` in your go routine and when you are done inside any of your go routines , Just make the `cancel()` `func()` call. and `ctx.done()` will be then true and then first case of switch will be true and it  will return from all of your go routines.

```
func miner( ctx context.Context,  blockNumber int, transactions string, previousHash string, zeroPrefix string, startNonce uint64, nonceChan chan uint64, hashChan chan string) {
    var text string
    var newHash string

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():  // if cancel() execute
           return
        default:
            text = strconv.Itoa(blockNumber) + transactions + previousHash + strconv.FormatUint(startNonce, 10)
            newHash = encrypt(text)

            if startswith(newHash, zeroPrefix) {
                nonceChan <- startNonce
                hashChan  <- newHash

                close(nonceChan)
                close(hashChan)
                break
            } else {
                startNonce++
            }

        }

    }
}

func mine(blockNumber int, transactions string, previousHash string, zeroPrefix int) Block {
    var prefixString string
    var newHash string
    var nonce uint64
    var startNonce uint64

    nonceChan := make(chan uint64)
    hashChan := make(chan string)

    for i := 0; i < zeroPrefix; i++ {
        prefixString += "0"
    }

    start := time.Now()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++{
        // This line is for deciding at what nonce value a miner should start at.
        startNonce = uint64((float64(i) / 4) * math.Pow(2, 64))

        go func(ctx context.Context) {
            fmt.Println("Started miner with start nonce of", startNonce)
            miner(ctx, blockNumber, transactions, previousHash, prefixString, startNonce, nonceChan, hashChan)
        }(ctx)
    }

    nonce = <- nonceChan
    newHash = <- hashChan
    cancel()

    // Here is where I would like to destroy the other three miners

    block := Block{
        blockNumber,
        transactions,
        previousHash,
        newHash,
        nonce,
        zeroPrefix,
        time.Since(start),
    }

    return block
}
```

Comment: Please put the context as first parameter: "The Context should be the first parameter, typically named ctx" (https://golang.org/pkg/context/)

Comment: @TehSphinX i have just updated my ans. thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: One upvote for using the right language construct. I'd also not pass in the cancel function. It can be cancelled from the outside after receiving the result.

Comment: totally agreed with you

Comment: H.R. Emon Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())` in the function that starts all goroutines and pass it to all goroutines (as first param in function).

When work should be cancelled, call `cancel` function. You can do this e.g. in the `main` function after receiving the result.

In each goroutine check with a select (in your `for` loop) for `ctx.Done`:

```golang
select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    return
default:
}

// continue mining
```

---

Example:

```golang
func miner(ctx context.Context, ...) {
    defer func() {
        // any necessary cleanup
    }

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // abort was called for: exit
            return
        default:
        }

        // continue mining
    }
}
```

```golang
func mine() {
    // use a single channel to get the result. You could 
    // block yourself if you use multiple channels
    chResult := make(chan result)

    // create context
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++{
        // ...

        // pass the context into the miner
        go miner(ctx, chResult, ...)
    }

    // block for first miner to be successful
    res := <-chResult
   
    // cancel the other routines
    cancel()
    
    // ...
}
```

`result` could be:

```golang
struct result {
    hash  string
    nonce uint64
}
```